# Landing page image for a salon

Tags: website-design, images, copyright, resource-recommendations, website-templates

I am trying to make a landing page for a company that provides grooming services (for females, like makeup artists, hairdressers etc). I am struggling to find a cover photo for the page due to copyright issues. I need help in finding, if there is a specific website/forum where I can find, images relative to my page.

I am relatively new in this field (designing websites and landing pages). I am looking for something that will describe the service. I am trying to copy a template using different pictures, colour schemes and layout.

Comment: You could take your own pictures or commission a photographer  - then there are no issues, otherwise there is a wide range of stock photo libraries where you can subscribe and purchase single images for a reasonable price.

Comment: I'm questioning your use of a "landing page." Do you mean the home page, or are you including an actual landing page where the visitor has to click an "Enter" link to get to the links? 

Landing pages are not user-friendly. Most website users want to get to the information right now. They dislike extra steps to get there.

Answer (score 4):

As someone who uses these kind of services (I'm a woman, I get my hair/nails done etc.) nothing annoys me more than stock images on a salon website.

I want to see where I'm going, how it looks, how the result looks. I want REAL feedback and images. Don't go for stock, but take (or have someone else do it) pictures of the real salon.

Don't use stock images for the services either. Take pictures of the products in use, in the environment they are going to be used in. This way the visitor will get a good idea of the environment and style of the salon. This is important to the Salon's clients.

Comment: I think it depends on the stock images. I agree that when someone dumps them in with a circle around, it looks cheesy. But if they're tweaked and prettied up in Photoshop for the specific website, I think they can work well. But I agree that actual salon photos are equally important.

Comment: @DocPixel well I guess it just has a lot of variables that need to be right. If I see a picture of a beautiful fresh face mask in a lovely bamboo bowl and when I get there I get a pre-made face mask from a plastic container I'm going to be disappointed. So if you take all those things in account and base your stock pictures on real facts then you could do it right, yes.

Comment: I agree that the stock images should not misrepresent products, absolutely. I would use stunning stock images to add to the look and feel, and would edit/enhance them... But I would photograph the actual products - using stock instead would be misrepresentation. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1):

> I am relatively new in this field.  (I am struggling to find a cover photo for the page due to copyright issues.)

Two things you need to know then.

- Avoid problems to your clients and yourself doing things right from start. Pay for thoose copyrights accordingly.
- Do not try to "solve" your clients needs using only free resources. Charge your client if your client needs a payed resource.

#### Find your images

You can google two things:

- **Stock photos** and compare prices, Normally the higher the price the more "exclusive" the content. It is either a new photo, or somehow has more "quality". Older and more worn out content is cheaper.

Keep track of what client buys what images. If you use the same image with diferent clients you need to pay them again. Keep a well organized track of your mail receipts.

- **Free stock photos** There are a few trully free images, and there are several more that need a clear atributtion. Explore them and respect the terms if you need to use them.

#### The best option

> a company that provides grooming services (for females, like makeup artists, hairdressers etc)

**There is a golden oportunity to make something exclusive!** Prepare a profesional photoshoot!

And hire a professional photographer please, and a beautiful model.

Answer (score 1):

### I just want to add some ideas to Jane's good answer.

Hire two models or ***better yet***, if the salon has some beautiful regulars offer them discounts/free services for a photo shoot *(a lot of young girls would take the offer in a second)* + hire a photographer to do the job.

Use this opportunity and think of the marketing campaigns you/they need. Take shots that you can use in facebook/google campaigns or print materials.

From one good photoshoot and some planning you can ensure your marketing campaign for almost a year.

Best of luck!

> PS: Don't forget the release contracts for the *"models"* if you will
>   be going for that. Better have yourself and your client covered.